# How to rearrange array using spaces?

Tags: c

I'm struggling with rearranging my array. I have used from single to multiple loops trying to put spaces (white characters) between two pairs of characters, but I was constantly rewriting the original input. So there is always an input of even length, for example `ABCDEFGH`. And my task would be to extend the size of the array by putting spaces after every 2 chars (except the last one). 
So the output would be:

```
AB CD EF GH
```

So the size of output (if I'm correct) will be `(2*input_len)-1`
Thanks.

**EDIT:** 
This is my code so far

```
// output = "ABCDEFGHIJKL
char c1;
  char c2;
  char c3;
  int o_len = strlen(output);
  for(int i = 2; i < o_len + olen/2; i = i + 3){
    if(i == 2){
      c1 = output[i];
      c2 = output[i+1];
      c3 = output[i+2];
      output[i] = ' ';
      output[i+1] = c1;
      output[i+2] = c2;
    }
    else{
      c1 = output[i];
      c2 = output[i+1];
      output[i] = ' ';
      output[i+1] = c3;
      output[i+2] = c1;
      c3 = c2;
    }
  }
```

So the first 3 pairs are printed correctly, then it is all a mess.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, describe what specific problem you have with it and ask a specific question related to that attempt.

Comment: New length is not `(2 * input_len) - 1` but `input_len + (int)(input_len / 2) - 1`.

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you rearranging your array in place or storing the result in another buffer?

Comment: If for each two elements you add one, that extends the number of required element be 0.5 of the number of input elements. So: `new = old + 0.5*old` or simply `new = 1.5*old`

Answer (score 3):

Presuming you need to store the space separate result, probably the easiest way to go about inserting the spaces is simply to use a pair of pointers (one to your input string and one to your output string) and then just loop continually writing a pair to your output string, increment both pointers by `2`, check whether you are out of characters in your input string (if so `break;` and nul-terminate your output string), otherwise write a `space` to your output string and repeat.

You can do it fairly simply using `memcpy` (or you can just copy 2-chars to the current pointer and `pointer + 1`, your choice, but since you already include `string.h` for `strlen()` -- make it easy on yourself) You can do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRSZ 128   /* constant for no. of chars in output string */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char *instr = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "ABCDEFGH",  /* in string */
        outstr[ARRSZ] = "",                         /* out string */
        *ip = instr, *op = outstr;                  /* pointers to each */
    size_t len = strlen (instr);                    /* len of instr */
    
    if (len < 4) {  /* validate at least 2-pairs worth of input provided */
        fputs ("error: less than two-pairs to separate.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (len & 1) {  /* validate even number of characters */
        fputs ("error: odd number of characters in instr.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (ARRSZ < len + len / 2) {  /* validate sufficient storage in outstr */
        fputs ("error: insufficient storage in outstr.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually */
        memcpy (op, ip, 2);             /* copy pair to op */
        ip += 2;                        /* increment ip by 2 for next pair */
        op += 2;                        /* increment op by 2 for next pair */
        if (!*ip)                       /* check if last pair written */
            break;
        *op++ = ' ';                    /* write space between pairs in op */
    }
    *op = 0;                            /* nul-terminate outstr */
    
    printf ("instr  : %s\noutstr : %s\n", instr, outstr);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strspaceseppairs
instr  : ABCDEFGH
outstr : AB CD EF GH

$ ./bin/strspaceseppairs ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQ
instr  : ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQ
outstr : AB CD EF GH IJ LM NO PQ
```

Odd number of chars:

```
$ ./bin/strspaceseppairs ABCDEFGHIJLMNOP
error: odd number of characters in instr.
```

Or short string:

```
$ ./bin/strspaceseppairs AB
error: less than two-pairs to separate.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Edit To Simply Output Single-Pair or Empty-String**

Based upon the comment by [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) it may make more sense rather than issuing a diagnostic for a short string, just to output it unchanged. Up to you. You can modify the first conditional and move it after the odd character check in that case, e.g.

```
    if (len & 1) {  /* validate even number of characters */
        fputs ("error: odd number of characters in instr.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (len < 4) {  /* validate at least 2-pairs worth of input provided */
        puts(instr);   /* (otherwise output unchanged and exit) */
        return 0;
    }
```

You can decide how you want to handle any aspect of your program and make the changes accordingly.

Comment: The test on the minimum length of input seems unnecessary and counterproductive: why not accept `AB` and output `AB`? Even the empty string would be handled gracefully.

Comment: That's a good point. I was just thinking about issuing a diagnostic if the string fed to the program didn't at least have two pairs. But we could do both I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a piece of code like the one below:
This function returns the output `splitted` array, as you requested to save it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char* split_by_space(char* str, size_t length, size_t step) {
    size_t i = 0, j = 0, spaces = (length  / step);
    char* splitted = malloc(length + spaces + 1);

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < length; ++i, ++j) {
        if (i % step == 0 && i != 0) {
            splitted[j] = ' ';
            ++j;
        }
        splitted[j] = str[i];
    }
    splitted[j] = '\0';
    return splitted;
}

int main(void) {
    // Use size_t instead of int.
    size_t step = 2; // Also works with odd numbers.
    char str[] = "ABCDEFGH";
    char* new_str;
    // Works with odd and even steps.
    new_str = split_by_space(str, strlen(str), step);
    printf("New splitted string is [%s]", new_str);
    // Don't forget to clean the memory that the function allocated.
    free(new_str);
    return 0;
}
```

When run with a step value of 2, the above code, outputs:

```
New splitted string is [AB CD EF GH]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209271/discussion-on-answer-by-hitter-how-to-rearrange-array-using-spaces).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void rearrange(char *str)
{
    int len=strlen(str),n=0,i;
    char *word=malloc((len+(int)(len/2)));
      
    if(word==NULL)
    {
       printf("Memory Error");
       exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if( i % 2 == 0 && i != 0)
        {
            word[n]=' ';
            n++;
            word[n]=str[i];
            n++;
        }
        else
        {
            word[n]=str[i];
            n++;
        }
    }
    
    word[n]='\0';
    strcpy(str,word);
    free(word);
    return;
}

int main()
{
     char word[40];

     printf("Enter word:");
     scanf("%s",word);

     rearrange(word);

     printf("\n%s",word);

     return 0;
 }
```

See Below:

The rearrange function saves the letters in str into word. if the current position is divisible by 2 i.e i%2 it saves one space and letter into str, otherwise it saves letter only.

Comment: Your answer should contain a description of how it works for the case of OP and also for future readers.

Comment: @Ronak Dhoot  Thank you for your response, i thought the down vote is for some technical errors, so i find some error in my code and corrected it but i can not get what is the exact error so why i asked for reason.

Comment: `if(i%2==0&&i!=0)`: the space bar is your friend, use it to make the code more readable for yourself and others too: `if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0)`

Comment: `sprintf(word+n,"%c",str[i]);` -> `word[n] = str[i];` and add the null terminator at the end. The overhead of using `sprintf` for this simple assignment probably exceeds **100x**

Answer (score 1):

Inserting characters inside the array is cumbersome and cannot be done unless you know the array is large enough to accommodate the new string.

You probably want to allocate a new array and create the modified string there.

The length of the new string is not `(2 * input_len) - 1`, you insert a space every 2 characters, except the last 2: if the string has 2 or fewer characters, its length is unmodified, otherwise it increases by `(input_len - 2) / 2`. And in case the length is off, you should round this value to the next integer, which is done in integer arithmetics this way: `(input_len - 2 + 1) / 2`.

Here is an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *reformat_with_spaces(const char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    size_t newlen = len > 2 ? len + (len - 2 + 1) / 2 : len;
    char *out = malloc(newlen + 1);

    if (out) {
        for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
                out[j++] = ' ';
            }
            out[j++] = str[i];
        }
        out[j] = '\0';
    }
    return out;
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[256];
    char *p;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if any
        p = reformat_with_spaces(buf);
        if (p == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
        puts(p);
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```